# Referencing the hasMany property in the controller

Tags: grails

My User has a hasMany property called watchlist containing a certain number of Stock Symbols and I want to show that watchlist on the web page.

```
static scaffold = User

def index() { 
    def stocks = StockSymbol.list(sort: "volume", order: "desc")
    def a = User.get(1)
    for(stock in a.watchlist)
    {
        println stock.name
        println stock.volume
        println stock.price

    }
    return [stocks: stocks]
}
```

So far this will print the information to the console. Is there anyway I can store that information and return like I am with the stocks object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the `user` instance to the view (`index.gsp`):

```
return [stocks: stocks, user: a]
```

and print all information you want:

```
<body>
    .
    .
    .
    <p>Watchlist of user ${user}</p>
    <ul>
    <g:each var="stock" in="${user.watchlist}">
        <li>${stock.name} | ${stock.volume} | ${stock.price}</li>             
    </g:each>
    </ul>
    .
    .
    .
</body>
```

Alternatively you could just pass the watchlist like this:

```
return [stocks: stocks, watchlist: a.watchlist]
```

By the way - you could ommit the `return` statement in Groovy.